New server is not supporting smtp plugin to set email service on wordpress site..need alternate ways to set up email on my site
i moved my website to a new serve but when i intall smtp plugin to set the email issue on website the site give me this error "There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions." and my site is not live anymore.how to resolve this issue.Do i need some server related configuration to make the smtp work.also mention that.
I deleted the smtp plugin from cpanel and website is live again but i need to set up email functionality on my site.need alternatives.
Thanks in advance.
